# How to update a PySpark RDD of dictionaries based on some condition

Tags: python, pyspark

Firstly I understand the concept of persistent data structures and immutability with regards to RDD's.. update is the only word I could think of :)

My question is:

Given an RDD of dictionaries (or Row objects) how can I loop/map across and apply some transformation login on that RDD and receive back a new RDD with those transformations applied. Example:

Given an RDD containing dictionaries:

```
fbb = sc.parallelize(
    [{'amount_gbp': -43.33,
      'balance_gbp': 57.08,
      'type': 'GED',
      'id': 961690979,
      'settled_jrnl_cr_datetime': u'(null)',
      'virtual_cash_balance': 0,
      'virtual_debt_balance': 0},
     {'amount_gbp': 17.08,
      'balance_gbp': 40.0,
      'type': 'OIP',
      'id': 962182953,
      'settled_jrnl_cr_datetime': u'(null)',
      'virtual_cash_balance': 0,
      'virtual_debt_balance': 0}])
```

I attempted to apply the function:

```
def update_virtual_cash_balance(x):
    x.update({'virtual_cash_balance': x['amount_gbp'] + x['balance_gbp']}) if x['type'] == 'GED' else x

   fbb.map(lambda x: update_virtual_cash_balance(x)).collect()
```

And expected:

```
[{'amount_gbp': -43.33,
  'balance_gbp': 57.08,
  'type': 'GED',
  'id': 961690979,
  'settled_jrnl_cr_datetime': u'(null)',
  'virtual_cash_balance': 13.75,
  'virtual_debt_balance': 0},
 {'amount_gbp': 17.08,
  'balance_gbp': 40.0,
  'type': 'OIP',
  'id': 962182953,
  'settled_jrnl_cr_datetime': u'(null)',
  'virtual_cash_balance': 0,
  'virtual_debt_balance': 0}]
```

But got:

```
Out[411]: [None, None]
```

Any help with what I am misunderstanding would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `update_virtual_cash_balance` doesn't return anything so you get `None`
- `update` method doesn't return anything so you would get `None` even if `update_virtual_cash_balance` returned value
- you shouldn't modify data in place. RDD is immutable and mutating data can have undesired effects.

Try:

```
def update_virtual_cash_balance(x):
    if x['type'] == 'GED':
        z = x.copy()  # shallow copy should be enough here
        z.update({'virtual_cash_balance': x['amount_gbp'] + x['balance_gbp']}
        return z
    return  x
```

Comment: It was not me whom downvoted @LostInOverflow Thanks for the help